# button that programmatically goes to a different view? C# (xamarin)

Tags: c#, ios, user-interface, xamarin

What code do I need to make the screen go to a different view via a button? I have a button and I want to press it to take me to a different screen in my mobile app. I'm using c# in xamarin. I'm aware that it can be done visually, but I would like to do it programmatically. Thank you in advance.

Comment: I'm using iOS, sorry I didn't specify

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android: `StartActivity(typeof(YourDestinationActivity));`

iOS: `NavigationController.PushViewController(YourDestinationController, true);`
For iOS you need a UINavigationController if you do it that way.